# <p> not adding page break

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid image, that shows the path through a maze.

I have everything working except for the grid system doesn't page break.

Example

[image: Example]

The desired result would be like this without space between the rows

[image: Desired]

Here is the source code (Note: this will be auto-generated by the app when I can get the display correct)

```css
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.white {
    background: white;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/form_styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried removing the 
 and I get the straight line.

How can I get the rows to actually be rows?

Comment: Because `p` can't be a parent of `div`, it's invalid html and you'll end up with empty `<p></p>` and all the `div`s will be outside it

Comment: You should probably change the `<p>` to a wrapping `<div>` instead.

Comment: When you say page break, do you mean line break?

Comment: Whoops yes. Been in Microsoft Word too long lol

Answer (score 2):

As Alon Eitan pointed out `<p>` tags aren't probably the best here. If you have control over the markup output, I would suggest changing the wraps to `<div>` or something similar:

```
<div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block white"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block green"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
            <div class="block red"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rowwrap {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.rowwrap::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.white {
    background: white;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

Because all your blocks float, you'll also need to clear them before the next row. I added a pseudo element to the `rowwrap` to do that.

Fiddle with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/zjedzyje/